# Advice with PHP API poster for Twitter

Tags: php, twitter

I have been looking for some simple code that will allow me to tweet from a PHP script.

Started to use this

```
https://www.madebymagnitude.com/blog/how-to-automatically-send-tweets-in-php/

# Define constants
define('TWITTER_USERNAME', 'YOUR_TWITTER');
define('CONSUMER_KEY', 'YOUR_KEY');
define('CONSUMER_SECRET', 'YOUR_SECRET_KEY');
define('ACCESS_TOKEN', 'YOUR_TOKEN');
define('ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET', 'YOUR_TOKEN_SECRET');

# Create the connection
$twitter = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
# Migrate over to SSL/TLS
$twitter->ssl_verifypeer = true;

$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange(array(
    'oauth_access_token' => ACCESS_TOKEN,
    'oauth_access_token_secret' => ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
    'consumer_key' => CONSUMER_KEY,
    'consumer_secret' => CONSUMER_SECRET
));
```

But no luck.

Is there a simple way to do this...

I have all the keys and secret keys

Comment: Looks like a good start. Could you post the error messages you are getting

Comment: @osowskit been using this page - but cant seem to get it to post

https://www.madebymagnitude.com/blog/how-to-automatically-send-tweets-in-php/

Comment: The date on that blog post is 27.09.2014 - that's 5 years ago. The Twitter API has changed considerably since then. I recommend trying https://github.com/jublo/codebird-php